# Scipt not Executing in Selected Tab to Send and Receive Messages

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am having trouble making a script run on a page.

Here is what my background.js looks like:

```
chrome.tabs.query({
  url: 'https://www.tradingview.com/*'
}, function(tabs) {
  if (tabs.length == 1) {
    var tabURL = tabs[0].url;
    alert(tabURL);
    alert(tabs[0].id);
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, {file: "getTradingData.js"}, function(){
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {greeting: "hello"}, function(response) {
            console.log(response.farewell);
          });
    });
  } else {
    alert("Please have one and only one tradingview chart page opened.");
  }
});
```

`chrome.tabs.executeScript(tabs[0].id, {file: "getTradingData.js"}` should be executing the script getTradingData.js but I don't think it is. I have an alert in the script that is not running, but does run as content script when I refresh the page.

Here is what ny getTradingData.js looks like:
alert("getTradingData.js is Running");

var myPort = chrome.extension.connect();

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    alert("got message");
    if (request.subject == "getPrice")
      sendResponse({
        msg: price
      });
  });
```

Finally here is my manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "Automated TradingView Strategy",
  "description": "This extension shows a Google Image search result for the current page",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["jquery-2.2.3.min.js", "background.js"]
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["https://www.tradingview.com/chart/*", "http://www.tradingview.com/*"],
      "js": ["jquery-2.2.3.min.js", "getTradingData.js"]
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "tabs",
    "https://ajax.googleapis.com/"
  ]
}
```

I need to be able to send data between "tradingview.com/chart/*" and the extension background.js. However, the script is not loading when I refresh the extension so it can't receive nor send messages.

Let me know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run the `getTradingData.js` using `executeScript` you must add the address of the site in  `permissions`.

```
"permissions": ["*://*.tradingview.com/*", "tabs"]
```

---

From `background` you send `{greeting: "hello"}`, but you do not accept these data in `getTradingData.js`. Therefore you do not get response.

```
console.log(response.farewell);
```

You do not send `response.farewell`. They will not be displayed.

---

```
if (request.subject == "getPrice") {

    sendResponse({msg: price});
}
```

Same. You get alerts only.

[Programmatic injection](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#pi)

Comment: Thank you. The permission was what I was missing. I have just started learning to code extensions today so I will do my best to figure out the rest.